# Does Snowflake support CTE with the EXCEPT operator

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two queries I believe are identical.  Each has a CTE.  To test, I want to use the EXCEPT operator.  Each of the two queries executes, but when I put the EXCEPT operator between, Snowflake throws an error saying "unexpected 'with' syntax error".  Does snowflake support CTEs in either side of an EXCEPT operator?

```
with cte as (select column from table)
select column from cte
except
with cte as (select column from table)
select column from cte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WITH is at the top. Shouldn't this be:

```
with cte1 as (select column from table), cte2 as (select column from table)
select column from cte1
except
select column from cte2
```